# Tkinter being fickle with pictures, some are blank, others are not

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library

NOTE: The main problem hasn't been solved, but the code does work on a Windows PC, the problem has something to with the computer I'm using.

As the title suggests, in my code, one image works perfectly fine, yet the other doesn't display correctly.

I feel like I'm overlooking something very obvious, regardless, this is the segment of code that I'm having trouble with.

```
from Tkinter import *
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from urllib import urlopen


url1 = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-bnh6_0GlqbA/VUKUsl1Pp9I/AAAAAAACGoM/Vx9yu1QGIKQ/s650/Sunset.png'
url2 = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_J57qf7Y9yI/VUPaEaMbp9I/AAAAAAACGuM/3f4551Kcd0I/s650/UpsideDawn.png'

window = Tk()

imagebytes = urlopen(url1).read()
imagedata = StringIO(imagebytes)
imagePIL = Image.open(imagedata)
imageready = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagePIL)

imagelabel = Label(window, image = imageready)
imagelabel.image = imageready

imagelabel.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

If you were to run this code, you'll find that url1 will display a blank window, but url2 will display the image.

Comment: Please `import io` then replace `imagedata = StringIO...` with `imagedata = io.BytesIO...` and see if that works.

Comment: That did not work, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works for me in Python 3, displaying either image just fine.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import urllib.request
import io

url1 = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-bnh6_0GlqbA/VUKUsl1Pp9I/AAAAAAACGoM/Vx9yu1QGIKQ/s650/Sunset.png'
url2 = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_J57qf7Y9yI/VUPaEaMbp9I/AAAAAAACGuM/3f4551Kcd0I/s650/UpsideDawn.png'

window = Tk()

imagebytes = urllib.request.urlopen(url1).read()
imagedata = io.BytesIO(imagebytes)
imagePIL = Image.open(imagedata)
imageready = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagePIL)

imagelabel = Label(window, image = imageready)
imagelabel.image = imageready

imagelabel.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

The following is my best guess at a Python 2 version of the above:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from urllib import urlopen
import io # try this

url1 = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-bnh6_0GlqbA/VUKUsl1Pp9I/AAAAAAACGoM/Vx9yu1QGIKQ/s650/Sunset.png'
url2 = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_J57qf7Y9yI/VUPaEaMbp9I/AAAAAAACGuM/3f4551Kcd0I/s650/UpsideDawn.png'

window = Tk()

imagebytes = urlopen(url1).read()
imagedata = io.BytesIO(imagebytes) # use bytesio instead of stringio
imagePIL = Image.open(imagedata)
imageready = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagePIL)

imagelabel = Label(window, image = imageready)
imagelabel.image = imageready

imagelabel.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: BytesIO has the same effect, a blank screen.

Comment: I just installed Python 2 and PIL/Pillow (32-bit version of Pillow), and the Python 2 version I posted works fine. Your issue might be environment-related.

Comment: Actually, I just tried the code in your question, and it displayed the image just fine as well. Definitely environment-related.

Comment: It could be that I'm using a mac (Mid-2010 model, running Yosemite)? I'll see if the code works on a Windows PC, then I'll come back.

Comment: I've tested this on a windows PC, and it worked, as it turns out, it is just my Mac that has a problem. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: The fact that one of the images displayed and the other didn't leads me to believe that there must be some solution to processing the bytes in a way that the Mac likes, but I sure don't know what it is. Sorry about that.